Can you have kubevirt VMs failover automatically when a node fails?
By failover I mean the kubevirt VMs that were on the failed node should be rebooted back up on a live node.
This is similar to how VMs run in a VMware cluster with HA capabilities.
Kubernetes clusters work a little different with kubevirt VMs.
Just wondering if anyone has HA and failover figured out with kubevirt VMs running in a kubernetes cluster
